# Better alternative for c++ old feature?

Tags: c++, language-features

c++ has come a long way, it has lot of feature that lead to do same task in n number of ways.
What feature do you think should be avoided and list better alternative for the same.

> Like use SmartPointers in places of
>   pointers

Comment: Please make community wiki - this is not a real question

Comment: done.I am asking for things like use Smartpointer in places of pointers

Comment: It's a real question for people  coming form C or even from older-style C++

Comment: Add no I get no rep for my answer. Arrgh

Comment: Every time I give a real good answer, someone community wikis it. I have a answer modded up 68 times, that I only got 150 rep for. CW joke questions or subjective, but come on.

Comment: What can I tell you. It's basically just a poll question on what things you should do in modern C++ - which has been asked and answered many times before

Comment: I looked at the related FAQ and instead of finding an "official" answer, I seem to have found an official expression of the community's disagreement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-in-stackoverflow

Comment: @tpdi, you have almost 5k rep. who needs more? :)

Comment: I have a sad and empty life. The rep is the only thing that gives me pleasure. Plus I sell it to WOW gold farmers.

Comment: @tpdi, you almost make me look for non-cw'ed answers of yours to upvote them... I said almost :)

Comment: Oh, my take on CW: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-in-stackoverflow

Comment: _Your_ take on CW: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-in-stackoverflow/718699#718699

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Avoid malloc, use new.

Avoid memcpy, use a copy constructor.

Avoid `#defines`, use `const`s.

[Avoid `(C-style) casts`, use `static_cast<C++>( style casts )`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791953/when-using-win32-code-in-your-modern-c-app-should-you-use-proper-casting/791969#791969)

Avoid macros, use templates.

Avoid post-increment if you can use pre-increment.

Avoid new, use collections of value types, let the collection deal with memory management.

Avoid pointers to new'd objects, use `boost::scoped_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr.`

Avoid writing your own code to traverse collections, use `<algorithm>`s

Avoid reinventing the wheel, see if boost has what you need.

Avoid "char * name" for storing strings, use std::string.

[Avoid `using namespace foo`, use `using foo::bar`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708089/c-using-namespaces-to-avoid-long-paths/708106#708106)

Avoid "static (internal linkage) declarations" use unnamed namespaces.

Comment: I can't agree with the generalization of avoiding using plain pointers by using smart pointers. There are at least two situations where plain pointers are useable: in case of interfacing with 3rd party libraries that use them, and in case of aggregations (zero-or-one multiplicity) where the aggregator doesn't own the refered object (implemented as pointer data member).

Comment: I actually use plain pointers for everything, and I sincerely don't remember the last bug I had which was even loosely related to them. Most of the times it's for consistency with existing code, but I would write brand new classes with them, too. Of course pointer members are private, you initialize them, you have design by contract, you don't play with ownership around, etc.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I just wanted to correctly attribute. On the pointer issue, there are legitimate reasons to use them,and it is possible to use them safely (after C, does just that). The advice is "avoid", not "never use".

Comment: @tpdi Thanks for the intention, I just thought that removing my name improved readability. I agree with your point. On pointers. :)

Comment: "Avoid writing your own code to traverse collections, use <algorithm>s" Although it's generally better to write your own new generic algorithm than to torture the existing ones, if there's no good fit for what you need. This usually happens when what you need is copy_if...

Answer (score 1):

use new style casts

static_cast,
const_cast,
reinterpret_cast,
dynamic_cast,

instead of C style casts which are no longer considered fully safe

also prefer using STL containers over dynamically resizing arrays at runtime